# Login mechanism used by IBM Maximo Anywhere apps

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I have been working on IBM Maximo Anywhere apps such as Work Approval and Work Execution for sometime now have few queries regarding the login mechanism used by these apps. To be specific as per my understanding anyone having access to maximo on that particular environment can login into the anywhere apps - is that a correct statement? and if yes then how does it work in a disconnected state? If for any reason maximo is down will it mean that the app will not be able to authenticate a user and hence unable to login as well? And alongwith that is there any other kind of authentication done for example LDAP etc? Are there any different kinds of login failure messages that are displayed depending on why the app isnt able to let the user login? or is it a common one saying "Login Failed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time the user ever logs into the application, they do have to have a connection to the Maximo server to authenticate.  We also validate that the user is authorized to use this particular mobile app. We have a security group for each mobile app that the user must be a member of. After the authentication and authorization finishes, we download, store, and sign the locally stored data with the username/password combination, so that on subsequent login attempts, if the server is down, we can fail over to the locally stored data.  This also guarantees that the locally stored data is protected.

We support all of the types of authentication configuration that base Maximo supports.

More information here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.0/security/c_authentication.html

Comment: Thanks for that. Also related to login, in a scenario where multiple  people have logged in while the device was connected and now the device has gone off network - will all the previous users be able to login or will it be just the immediate user who had logged in before it went off? Does anywhere store multiple sets of data for every user who logged in or will it just be the data pertaining to the user who most recent user who logged in?

Comment: yes, each user's previously stored data is stored in a separate location.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand, every user who has previously logged in when the device was connected to maximo(online) will be able to login even after the device goes offline, irrespective if he was the recent user or not. Is that a correct statement?